# Installing packages onto R

Tags: r, installation, package, cran

For some reason I am suddenly not able to install packages in R (I have subsequently updated to the latest version of R and am running Windows 7). For example, if I type:

```
install.packages('beeswarm')
```

> Installing package into ‘D:/Rlibs’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- trying URL 'http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/beeswarm_0.1.5.zip'
>   Content type 'text/html' length unknown opened URL downloaded 1859
>   bytes
>
> Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package",
>   "Type")) :    cannot open the connection In addition: Warning
>   messages: 1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting
>   from zip file 2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"),
>   c("Package", "Type")) :   cannot open compressed file
>   'beeswarm/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

I have read that in Windows 7 there can be important restrictions on rights to writing to certain folders etc. so I've gone to some lengths to install R and library folders in non-default areas of my computer, and to allow myself rights to certain folders, but to no avail. Possibly also of importance is when I type:

```
.libPaths()

# [1] "D:/Rlibs"                                             
# [2] "C:/Users/L.Halsey/Documents/R/win-library/3.0"        
# [3] "C:/Users/L.Halsey/Documents/Documents/R-3.0.1/library"
```

I have created several folders in an attempt to create one that I could successfully install libraries into and set them up to be recognised by R using 'environment variables' from the start button. I don't know how to delete any of them though - not sure if this is relevant to my overall problem of not now being able to install/update packages for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

The error being reported is inability to open a connection. In Windows that is [often a firewall problem and is in the Windows R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e).  The usual first attempt should be to run internet2.dll. From a console session you can use:

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

(You are correct in thinking this is not due to your library setup. The error says nothing about permissions.) I don't think just typing `.libPaths` should return that character vector since on my machine I would need to type `.libPaths()` to see something like that. If you wanted to reduce the number of places for libraries you can use the `.libPaths` function for setting the values. This would pick the second and third of the existing paths

```
 .libPaths( .libPaths()[2:3] )
```

The inner call retrieves the path vector and the outer call sets it to a reduced vector.

Answer (score 7):

Running RStudio as administrator fixed it for me!

Answer (score 3):

I will probably duplicate a lot of other answers on the stackoverflow, but I got exactly the same error as OP, namely:
`Warning messages: 1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file 2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : cannot open compressed file 'zoo/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`

Turned out, while I as a user had permissions to write in a certain directory, R did not. In order to be sure you don't have something similar, do following:

1. get a usb drive, let's name it E
2. download package source as a .zip file and store it onto usb-drive in some directory, let's name it E:/source
3. Create directory for libraries on the usb drive, let's name it E:/libs
4. Install packages calling R command `install.package` from the R console and setting all relevant directories to point to your usb drive:

   (here I use package zoo as an example)

   ```
   install.packages("E:/source/zoo_1.7-12.zip", 
                    destdir = 'E:/source',  # no "/" after the path
                    lib = 'E:/libs', 
                    repos = NULL)
   ```
5. Load the package from the directory, where you installed it:

   `library('zoo', lib.loc = 'E:/libs')`

---

After you are sure, it works this way on your usb drive, you can start resolving directories permissions, and try out by changing the paths in the code above.

**update:**
In some windows environments even your usb-stick might be protected from read-write by the R. Make sure you check the permissions using the machine you are working from.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (based on the answer above)

```
install.packages("clustvarsel", lib = "C:/Users/dnentchev/My Programs/R-3.2.2/library")
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I turned the windows firewall off, and Run RStudio as administrator. so, that error fixed.