# R update.packages successfully downloaded but error during install

Tags: r, install.packages

I just upgraded my R, copied all my previous packages to the the new install folder, and then ran `update.packages()`. It downloaded 138 packages, but then during unpacking of the zips, it managed to unpack only 4 of the packages before stopping with the error

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Unlike [another question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680618/installing-packages-onto-r), mine stopped with just the error above without any other warning messages (and the solution in the other question) didn't work.

I managed to find all the zips locally. Is there a way for me to just complete the unpacking of the remaining 134 using the local zips?

FWIW, I tried the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339796/loading-an-r-package-from-a-custom-directory) to use `devtools` but when install package for `devtools`, it hit the same error during unpacking *sigh*

Comment: Have you tried running R as an administrator? This usually fix these update/install problems for me.

Comment: I have full admin rights.

I'm on Windows 8.1, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are all of the downloaded zip files correct (not corrupted)? Pick a couple of the failed ones, check the md5sum with CRAN's, and see if it's a download problem. (Just a stab.) Have you made any updates to `.libPaths()`?

Comment: If you provide one or two of the packages ***and their checksum*** (md5sum, sha1sum, or sha256sum, your choice), I'll see if the same zipfile installs fine on my win81/r-3.2 system. (Speaking of that, please update your question with `sessionInfo()`.)

Comment: (I mean the name of the package ... I'm not suggesting you try to attach zipfiles.)

Comment: Apologies I'm unable to reproduce the problems. The folder where all the zips are is gone (didn't occur to me to copy the content of the temporary folder), and when I tried to update the packages again this morning, everything worked like a charm.

But I think you may be right that perhaps the earlier zip files were corrupted. Thanks for that suggestion, something for me to look out for in subsequent updates.