# Plotting regression line equation (order of 2) in each plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have been working on some code to iterate creating scatter plots based on data from a data frame and exporting each scatter plot with an 2nd order regression line to a single PDF file with each page as its own scatter plot.  What I would like to do is produce the regression line equation and place it in the top left margin of the scatter plot for each iteration.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

plot_5 <-
    Infil_Data2 %>% 
    split(.$Site_ID) %>% 
    map2(names(.),
         ~ggplot(.x, aes(Sqrt_Time.x, Cal_Vol_cm)) + 
         geom_point() +
         labs(title = paste(.y)) +
         theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
         stat_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Sqrt_Time.x, y = Cal_Vol_cm),
                     method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
                     formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE),
                     color = "red") +
         theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")))


    pdf("allplots5.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
    walk(plot_5, print)
    dev.off()
```

Here is a sample of the `Infil_Data2` dataframe that I am using:

```
Infil_Data2 <-
    structure(list(Time = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
    210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
    210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
    210L, 240L, 270L, 300L), Site_ID = c("H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
    "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", 
    "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", 
    "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3"), Vol_mL = c(63, 62, 
    60, 59, 58, 56, 54, 52.5, 50, 48.5, 46.5, 82, 77, 73, 68, 65, 
    51, 56, 52, 47.5, 42.5, 37.5, 69, 67, 65, 63, 61, 60, 58, 56, 
    54, 51.5, 49), Sqrt_Time.x = c(0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
    10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
    16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
    10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
    16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
    10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
    16.43167673, 17.32050808), Cal_Vol_cm = c(0, 0.124339799, 0.373019398, 
    0.497359197, 0.621698996, 0.870378595, 1.119058194, 1.305567893, 
    1.616417391, 1.80292709, 2.051606688, 0, 0.621698996, 1.119058194, 
    1.74075719, 2.113776588, 3.854533778, 3.232834782, 3.730193979, 
    4.289723076, 4.911422072, 5.533121068, 0, 0.248679599, 0.497359197, 
    0.746038796, 0.994718394, 1.119058194, 1.367737792, 1.616417391, 
    1.865096989, 2.175946488, 2.486795986)), row.names = c(NA, 33L
    ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For questions like this, you should provide a small reproducible example; `Infil_Data` is undefined and you haven't provided the libraries you are using (e.g. like the one used for the `walk` command you are calling). Also, `mytable` is defined but not used, is this supposed to be the same as `Infil_Data`?

Comment: Thanks steveb, is there anything else I need to add or clear up?

Comment: If a function is used in your code sample, you should include lines like `library(ggplot2)`, `library(purrr)`, etc. If \mytable` isn't used, you should remove it as it is not relevant to the question. If you have another question, then that is where it should go.

Comment: Okay, I will remove it.  I just put it there because it was part of my overall code and was connected to the picture that I provided.  Thanks for the comments on how to make my questions better.

Comment: Can you run `dput(Infil_Data)` and put the results in place of what you have `tibble::tribble(......)`. So you would set `Infil_Data` to the results of `dput`.

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your question should include code that works making this reproducible.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as is.

Comment: Sorry, I have been away for a few days.  I reformatted my question and made the changes you suggested.  I ran the code in my Rstudio and it works for me.  Does it work for you?

Comment: No worries. Question, your code produces a list of plots, however, only the first element of the list appears to have a plot that produces non empty results. To simplify this question, and make it more reproducible, it would be a good idea to have the minimum number of plots required to answer the questions (2 or 3?). Also, ensuring that all plots actually plot data.

Comment: Okay, it should work now, producing 3 plots (H1, H2, and H3).  Let me know if it does not.

Comment: I provided an answer which should address what you are looking for. I edited your code to achieve two outcomes: (1) one can cut/paste the code as is and it should work (including the data), (2) fixed the indentation for the call to the plotting code.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what you did and the [Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) post, the code below produces a pdf with one plot per page, and with the equation in the plots. The equations appear in the same relative place on the plot even though the scales are changing. The original code in the question was very close and the code below only adds the call to `stat_smooth_func`.

```
# Input data.
Infil_Data2 <-
structure(list(Time = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
210L, 240L, 270L, 300L), Site_ID = c("H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
"H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", 
"H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", 
"H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3"), Vol_mL = c(63, 62, 
60, 59, 58, 56, 54, 52.5, 50, 48.5, 46.5, 82, 77, 73, 68, 65, 
51, 56, 52, 47.5, 42.5, 37.5, 69, 67, 65, 63, 61, 60, 58, 56, 
54, 51.5, 49), Sqrt_Time.x = c(0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 7.745966692, 9.486832981, 
10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 14.49137675, 15.49193338, 
16.43167673, 17.32050808), Cal_Vol_cm = c(0, 0.124339799, 0.373019398, 
0.497359197, 0.621698996, 0.870378595, 1.119058194, 1.305567893, 
1.616417391, 1.80292709, 2.051606688, 0, 0.621698996, 1.119058194, 
1.74075719, 2.113776588, 3.854533778, 3.232834782, 3.730193979, 
4.289723076, 4.911422072, 5.533121068, 0, 0.248679599, 0.497359197, 
0.746038796, 0.994718394, 1.119058194, 1.367737792, 1.616417391, 
1.865096989, 2.175946488, 2.486795986)), row.names = c(NA, 33L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Plotting code

```
# For the "stat_smooth_func", use the Laurae package.
# devtools::install_github("Laurae2/Laurae")

library(gridExtra)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(Laurae)

plot_5 <-
    Infil_Data2 %>% 
    split(.$Site_ID) %>% 
    map2(names(.),
         ~ggplot(.x, aes(Sqrt_Time.x, Cal_Vol_cm)) + 
         geom_point() +
         labs(title = paste(.y)) +
         theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
         stat_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Sqrt_Time.x, y = Cal_Vol_cm),
                     method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
                     formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE),
                     color = "red") +
         theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")) +
         stat_smooth_func(geom="text", method = "lm", hjust=0, parse=TRUE))


pdf("allplots5.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
walk(plot_5, print)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I added the single line, but am getting an error: "geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label".

Comment: A couple of things. Did you cut/paste from my post into your R session, including the setting of `Infil_Data2 ` ? Also, it might be worth restarting R (under menu **Session**, there is the **Restart R** option in RStudio).

Comment: Yes I cut/paste from your post.  What do you mean the setting of         Infil_Data2?  I also restarted R.

Comment: See my edit with the `Laurae` package. Apparently I had `stat_smooth_func` in my environment but it wasn't included in my code. If this doesn't resolve your issue, then there is likely something else that differs from our environments.

Comment: For "setting of Infil_Data2", I mean cut / paste from the post to ensure that `Infil_Data2` matches what is in this post. Essentially I am suggesting starting with an environment that is "clean'ish".

Comment: I tried adding Laurae from Github, but am running into the error of: "Error in read.dcf(path) : 
  Found continuation line starting '    modeling. ...' at begin of record."

Comment: What platform are you on, is it Windows ? I googled your error and found a link with a similar issue with a different package, but the workaround may be the same : [Error in read.dcd](https://github.com/psoerensen/qgg/issues/3). Also, what version of R and `devtools` are you using.

Comment: The following link may address your question [Installing packages onto R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680618/installing-packages-onto-r). My prediction is you are on a Windows machine all search results I looked at are Windows related.

Comment: I am using windows.  I am using 2.0.1 version of devtools and I am on version 1.1.456 of R.  I will read though the links you have provided tomorrow and get back to you with further questions if the workaround does not work.  Cheers.

Comment: I also have to add the ability to put higher order polynomials into the equation annotation / text on the plot.

Comment: Sorry that should have read 3.5.1 version of R.  I did just update it to 3.5.2.  I am also asking the github community about my problem with Laurae.  I will comment here when I eventually get it to work.

Comment: Hey steveb, I was able to get some help from a user on the R studio community because I could not get yours to work.  See comment below.

Comment: stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
 label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.90, #set the position of the eq
 formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), parse = TRUE, rr.digits = 3))